# Create a Service instance with reference type parameter?

Tags: android, android-service

I started my first own library for my Android projects, and im working on a service now.

I would like to pass a parameter to my service before `.startService()`

I used to call services like this:

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(ctxHere, MyServiceClass.class);
startService(myIntent);
```

So as far as i see, i cannot call a constructor to MyServiceClass this way, so i could not pass a parameters either.

It would be important that i should pass a reference type (a container) to my service instance on creating event.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "a container"? Why is this data not packaged as an extra on the `Intent` used with `startService()`? How are you intending to avoid the memory leak you will create by having the `Service` hold onto some object that comes from outside the `Service`? Note that there is nothing before `startService()`.

Comment: I would like to use this service in my other app's that needs locationing. I would like to pass a List<String> to this service to save locations. I cannot do this with putExtra() or am I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to pass a List to this service to save locations

You can [use `putStringArrayListExtra()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) to put an `ArrayList<String>` as an extra on an `Intent`.